# Question on measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis

I saw a part of proof in Royden Real analysis. 
Let $O$ be an open set, then $O$ is the union of a countable collection of disjoint open intervals ${I_n}$ so $\sum l(I_n) = m(I_n) < mE + \epsilon/2$. Thus there exists N such that $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty l(I_n) < \epsilon/2 $. I wonder how can we reach to the last statement? Any theorem saying that?

Answer (score 0):

It is the tail of a convergent series: as such, you can make it arbitrarily small provided that you discard sufficiently many terms at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty m(I_n) < m(E) + \epsilon/2 $ implies $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)\le m(E)$. Hence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)$ converges. So, for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^\infty l(I_n)<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.